# maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved

Tags: maven, maven-compiler-plugin

Today I convert a dynamic web project to a Maven project, so I can add all dependencies that my project requires. But when the IDE converted the project, an error on pom.xml appears.

On the plugin tag I receive this:

```
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:testCompile
```

I read about the error on other stack pages and I installed Maven again, deleted the .lastuploaded files about maven-compiler-plugin.

And I thought it was enough. So, I tried to run as Maven build with the goal: clean install

and I received this error:

```
- maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved
```

Then I tried to see the Maven compiler plugin folder (org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-compiler-plugin) when I noticed that the plugin is created and is updated. So I don't know why this happens. If the plugin is in my project folder and it is updated why did I receive this error?

Edit: my pom.xml

```xml
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>PlatformA</groupId>
        <artifactId>PlatformA</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
        <build>
            <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.5.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>
```

Comment: Check your proxy/firewall configuration...cause that sounds like a network issue...

Answer (score 0):

You can try following solutions -

- Try with force update of dependencies using -U option. This will download the dependencies again.
- Double check whether eclipse is pointing to correct settings.xml which is intended to.
- If you are under enterprise proxy, check the proxy settings in maven settings.xml and also in eclipse network configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Delete `3.5.1` (the version number maven is failing to resolve) folder in `~/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/` so that maven will re-download it again. That fixed the problem for me.